# MongoDb bulkWrite is not updating my document in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use MondodDB `bulkWrite` for the first time. I want to update multiple documents and remove ids that match the filter that I provided. I read that I could use MongoDB `bulkWrite` for this action. For this application, there is a Post model and User model. The Post model has an object value called `postLikes` which contains array of likes. These likes are simply the userId of the user who liked the post. So, I would like to remove their ids from this `postLikes` array when a selected user is deleted. Selected users to be deleted could be more than 2. When they are selected, their `ids` are passed as array to the backend in a variable called `selectedIds`. It is these `ids` that I would like to update the `Post` model and remove them from the `postLikes` array. This can only happen if there is a like by selected user.

It is a MERN stack application.
Here is my code:

```
const deleteSelectedUsers = async (req, res)=>{
    const {selectedIds} = req.body;// this is an array of selected ids sent from frontend
     //find all posts
    const posts = await Post.find();
    //get filter and return all posts with likes.
    const filteredPost = posts.filter((singleFilter) => singleFilter.postLikes.length !== 0)

     const updatedPosts = filteredPost.map((obj)=>{
    
        selectedIds.map((single)=>{
            //this checks to ensure that there is a like by the user and only that id is removed
            if(obj.postLikes.includes(single)){
               return {
                    updateOne: {
                        filter: { _id: obj._id },
                        update: { $pull: { postLikes: single } },
                    },
                    };
            }
            //console.log(obj.postLikes.includes(single))
        })
    })
  Post.bulkWrite(updatedPosts).then((res) => {
    console.log("Documents Updated", res.modifiedCount)
    })
  
  }
  }
```

No response from this code at all and update not made. How best can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using `.map` inside another `.map` without even `return`ing inside the first `.map`. This is generating an array of `undefined` values. From what I understand the question, a better solution would be:

```
const findIntersection = (array1, array2) => {
  return array1.filter((elem) => {
      return array2.indexOf(elem) !== -1;
  });
}

const filteredPost = posts.filter((singleFilter) => {
  const intersection = findIntersection(selectedIds, singleFilter.postLikes);
  return singleFilter.postLikes.length !== 0 && intersection.length !== 0;
});

const updatedPosts = filteredPost.map((obj)=>{
  const intersection = findIntersection(selectedIds, obj.postLikes);
  return {
    updateOne: {
      filter: { _id: obj._id },
      update: { $pull: { postLikes: { $in: intersection } } },
    },
  };
});
```

With the updated code, `updatedPosts` now contain correct mongoose/mongodb commands. Note the use of `$in` here. Since you want to remove from `postLikes` multiple matching values, rather than creating separate `updateOne`s for each matching value we're sending all of them in a single `udpateOne` with the use of `$in`.

You could trim down your code even further which is avoiding the finding of the intersection since `$in` takes care of that part. `{$pull : { postLikes: { $in: [...] }}}` will ensure that if the value inside the array matches any element in the specified array, it will remove that. Example:

```
const updatedPosts = filteredPost.map((obj)=>{
  return {
    updateOne: {
      filter: { _id: obj._id },
      update: { $pull: { postLikes: { $in: selectedIds } } },
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to write this code. I have implemented it but it is not working. Like, when I passed  updatedPosts to the bulkWrite and consoled it like this:  Post.bulkWrite(updatedPosts).then((res) => {
        console.log("Documents Updated", res.modifiedCount)
        }) . I got Documents Updated 2 but when I checked database, the matched ids are still there. This means they didn't get removed.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `filteredPost.map`? Also what is the format of in which `postLikes` stored in `Post`?  Is it an instance of `string` or `ObjecId`? And I'm assuming `selectedIds` is an array of `string`.

Comment: The filteredPost.map is passed to a variable called updatedPost and when I console.log it, this is what I saw: [
  { updateOne: { filter: [Object], update: [Object] } },
  { updateOne: { filter: [Object], update: [Object] } }
]. The postLikes are stored this way: postLikes: [0: objectId: ('
628cf9814aea9c5450a6f4ae') 1: objectId: ('62dec4eb28cd1c2b1c3e4877')]. The selecteIds is an array of strings.

Comment: Try: `update: { $pull: { postLikes: { $in: selectedIds.map(e => return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)) } } }`. Also use `inspect` from `util` library when you're logging the output of `filteredPost.map`. That way all the embedded objects will be printed (and not `[Object]` in case of your printed output).

Comment: So, I tried this new code, it didn't do anything. No response. The inspect from util. I quickly read about it and used it this way after requiring it: util.inspect(updatedPosts). I still got this: [
  { updateOne: { filter: [Object], update: [Object] } },
  { updateOne: { filter: [Object], update: [Object] } }
]. Maybe I am not using it properly.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I solved my problem after almost giving up.
I stored the ids the admin selected in a variable like this:

```
cost {selectedIds} = req.body;
```

I found all the available posts first like this:

```
const posts = await Post.find();
```

Then, I filtered out posts that have no likes at all:

```
const filteredPost = posts.filter((singleFilter) => singleFilter.postLikes.length !== 0)
```

I returned the filtered posts ids like this:

```
  const newPost = filteredPost.map((singleMap) => singleMap._id);
```

Then, I removed the selected users' ids from the filtered posts; `postLikes` like this using mongoose method:

```
  const updated = await Post.updateMany({ _id: {$in:  newPost} }, { $pull: { postLikes: { $in: selectedIds } } })
```

What I discovered is that the mongoose `$in` needed to be used while passing the filtered posts id.
Everything is working fine. This can help anyone facing similar challenge.